# Membership Director change

Tags: email, configuration

We recently changed Membership director, but the old director stills receives email notification when new member sign up.

How do we change that?

In general, how do we set-up email forwarding?  Cannot find references!

Comment: was the below answer useful. it is great having a community project like this you can ask questions, but it works best if you engage a bit with the answers

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of 'email forwarding'. It could be that you have bcc set up on the Thank You page settings of your Contribution Pages, so check under Contributions > Manage contribution pages, then click Configure for each of your Contribution pages, and head to the Thank You and Receipting tab.

If you have db access you can look in the civicrm_contribution_page table for emails.